# SFSafariViewController missing top bit on iphoneX

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x, sfsafariviewcontroller

I made tint colour black to better demonstrate this, but for `SFSafariViewController` is missing top bit on iphoneX. I checked twitter and theirs is present.

If I scroll down I can see website contents where the missing bit is

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone X status bar black web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876033/iphone-x-status-bar-black-web-app)

Comment: @LGP The question you've linked is about web apps, while this question is about `SFSafariViewController`.

Comment: @Ilja were you able to fix this?

Comment: @BrunoLemos It will keep happening if you hide statusbar in xcode, leave it enabled and hide it in your app's logic when this view is not active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced this bug when presenting `SFSafariViewController` while status bar was being hidden.

Solved it by configuring `modalPresentationStyle` to `.overCurrentContext`:

```
let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
safari.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(self, animated: true, completion: completion)
```

Hint: without configuring `modalPresentationStyle`, Safari presentation will have a push like transition.

Comment: Nice solution, but it doesn't work with View controller-based status bar appearance = NO

Comment: @AlexanderKhitev UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance is introduced in iOS 7 and defaults to YES. The older, UIApplication-based API is deprecated since iOS 9 and is unavailable when compiling extensions. Solution: migrate your code to use the new, non-deprecated logic.